# Tangled up iCloud photos

Tags: ios, icloud, photos

I have my iPhone photos auto-uploaded to the iCloud.

When my son got home from college, all his photos also uploaded to the iCloud.

Consequently,  I have thousands of his photos intermixed with all of my photos, and now we both have all of each others photos on our iPhones.

How can I separate out our two libraries?

PS: we both share the same AppleID.

Comment: Both iPhones use the same Apple ID? Please [edit] your question and update your answer with that and *any* other relevant info (and not in the comments).

Comment: Do you both only have iPhones or is there a Mac involved as well?

Comment: Apparently we have the same Apple ID.  We’ll need to change that.  There is no Mac involved,  just our 2 iphones.

Comment: Having no computer will make this a bit difficult. Do you have access to a computer which has enough disk space to temporarily hold all the photos?